# Better to return Task<List<T>> or IEnumerable<T> via WebAPI endpoint?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

Consider the following two examples:

## Option 1

Synchronous endpoint and repo call does not load entities into memory, returns `IEnumerable<T>` as result:

**MyController**

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetAll() {
    IEnumerable<T> result = _repo.GetAll();

    return Ok(result);
}
```

**MyRepo**

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll() {
    return GetSet<T>(); // EF DbSet (IQueryable<T>)
}
```

---

## Option 2

Asynchronous controller and repo call loads entities into memory (though asynchronously):

**MyController**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAll() {
    List<T> result = await _repo.GetAll();

    return Ok(result);
}
```

**MyRepo**

```
public Task<List<T>> GetAll() {
    return GetSet<T>().ToListAsync(); // EF DbSet (Task<List<T>>)
}
```

---

## Which is better?

What's the preferred method? To "stream" results or pre-load results asynchronously? To me, it seems that any form of `ToList` coming from a database table/query of unknown size is a bad move, and I generally avoid it. But I also want to gain from `async/await` benefits. Currently, any of my repo methods which return more than one entity are non-async, and others are async.

Comment: Your query needs to be materialized before returning a response. That's the only thing you need to worry about. What's the lifetime of the DbContext? Remember, clients cannot access the DbContext so all data must be read before returning. Lazy loading is not supported in a Web Api scenario

Comment: `DbContext` is per-request so the query (in option 1) is not executed until leaving my controller. My understanding is that ASP.NET will "stream" the enumerable to the response's output stream (e.g. not loading the result into memory first).

Comment: I would go for option 2, but in real life I would map them to a dto and possible do some modifications. Imho the needs of the data returned in  an api most likely differs from the model in EF

Comment: They are mapped before being returned, this example is highly simplified.

Comment: You're suggesting the repo should return an `IEnumerable`/`IQueryable`, and the controller should `ToListAsync()` it?

Comment: Well, we had full blown repositories before. Then changed to async support and ended up exposing the IQueryable to the api layer. So yes, that's what I would do.

Comment: You might be interested to check this article : http://www.claudiobernasconi.ch/2013/07/22/when-to-use-ienumerable-icollection-ilist-and-list/

Comment: @HadiHassan Thanks, I understand that intimately already -- more asking about `async` vs. `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Nevermind Josh, I was misreading your question

Comment: async will help you in releasing the thread till your loading job to finish, which is a great. The only question here in which format you will return the data and that is why i posted the link.

Comment: I think ToListAsync should be there in the repo layer since this will actually run a select query against database. In Web farm this will be an issue is not session is maintained properly.

Comment: @Thanigainathan Then every repo call is pulling the entire set into memory.

Comment: @JoshM. its better t o have a service layer between repo layer and controller which will do this. better for unit testing too.

Comment: `Synchronous endpoint and repo call does not load entities into memory` - are you sure about that? An easy way to check is to examine the response's `Content-Length` header; if it's there, then ASP.NET *is* sucking the entire result set into memory before writing the response.

Comment: @StephenCleary Good point, it seems you're likely to be correct. :)